Rust Optimizations Unexpectedly Not Improving Performance
I have a Rust function that's a bottleneck in my application. I attempted to optimize it, but I'm not seeing the expected performance improvement. Here's what I did:
fn my_function() -> Vec<f64> {
    let mut my_arr = vec![1.0; 30];
    for i in 0..30 {
        my_arr[i] = // calculations to get the value
    }
    my_arr
}

fn another_func(arr: &[f64; 30]) -> i32 {
    let value = rnd_val;
    for i in 0..arr.len() {
        if value < arr[i] {
            return i as i32;
        }
    }
    29
}

Optimized Version
fn my_function() -> i32 {
    let value = rand_val;
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 30 {
        if value < /* calculations to get the value */ {
            return i as i32;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    29
}

In the optimized version, I combined the two functions to avoid creating the my_arr vector and potentially reduce the number of iterations. However, I'm not seeing any significant performance improvement in my application.
I performed profiling on both versions, and the results show that allocations have been completely eliminated in the new version. However, despite this improvement, I'm not seeing any significant performance gain in my application.
What could be the reason for this lack of overall improvement, given that allocations have been removed? Are there any other factors I should consider or additional optimizations I could try?
Additional context:

The calculation to get the value is just some divisions and sums without any new variable.
The function is called nearly 22000000 per second

Thank you for your insights!
EDIT:
I wrote a complete example comparing both versions of the code, I saw that the results in second version are faster than in the first one, but In the whole application I still don't see the improvement.
use rand::Rng;

fn bottleneck1(values: [f64; 30], exp: f64) -> Vec<f64> {
    let e = exp.exp();
    let mut my_arr = vec![1.0; 30];
    for i in 0..30 {
        my_arr[i] = values[i] / (values[i] + e);
    }
    my_arr
}

fn another_func(arr: &[f64]) -> i32 {
    let value: f64 = rand::thread_rng().gen();
    for i in 0..arr.len() {
        if value < arr[i] {
            return i as i32;
        }
    }
    29
}

fn bottleneck2(values: &[f64; 30], exp: f64) -> i32 {
    let value: f64 = rand::thread_rng().gen();
    let e = exp.exp();
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 30 {
        if value < values[i] / (values[i] + e) {
            return i as i32;
        }
        i += 1;
    }

    return 29;
}

fn main() {
    let mut values = [0.0; 30];
    let exp = rand::thread_rng().gen();
    for i in 0..30 {
        values[i] = rand::thread_rng().gen();
    }
    let now = std::time::Instant::now();
    let mut result: i32 = 0;
    for _ in 0..1000000 {
        let my_arr = bottleneck1(values, exp);
        result += another_func(&my_arr);
    }

    println!("Time taken: {:?}", now.elapsed());
    println!("Result: {}", result / 1000000);

    result = 0;
    let now = std::time::Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..1000000 {
        result += bottleneck2(&values, exp);
    }
    println!("Time taken: {:?}", now.elapsed());
    println!("Result: {}", result / 1000000);
}


the results of this code on my machine are
Time taken: 887.668071ms
Result: 20
Time taken: 376.579158ms
Result: 20


It looks like you have used an llm to generate this question, which is not allowed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy

Hello, I Use an LLM to help me with the syntax and grammar because English is not my native language.

First question: are you compiling with --release?

@Chayim Friedman  it is compiled in --release mode [profile.release] opt-level = 2  I notice that opt-level 2 is faster than level 3 on my case

This question is impossible to answer by the code provided alone. Please create a Minimal Reproducible Example.

I added a full example comparing both versions in the question, thanks to everyone in advance.

This does not reproduce the effect you see on your real code so it's not a minimal reproducible example.

From your description it seems very likely you've misidentified the bottleneck and the real bottleneck is elsewhere.

I think the same as Cafce25 but when we optimized this function with other reactors the improvement in the time was notorious, just in this case when we did not see change.

So you are claiming that 887.668071ms to  376.579158ms is not significant. I would say that it is. Especially since your test indicates 100,000 iterations opposed to the expected 22,000,000.

Since your optimization is not significant, its just dividing the actions and one less allocation, and the "costly" thing here is the calculation, especially division which is the most expensive for computers to perform (not one allocation), your changes shouldn't be visible.
What happens in your code is many times far from what the machine actually perform, you have the compiler (and in this case a good one) that edit the code when its redundant (its possible that your changes we're already in the compiled code), and on top of the compiler the machine itself perform optimization on the tasks and rearrange them, if the changes are a small they might be transparent.
If you really want to check if the results are more efficient you should check the compiled code (find a way to make it assembly and check the effect of your changes).
